# Create Link to a Document on SharePoint Online

Tags: sharepoint-online, csom

I'm trying to create a link to a document using CSOM in SharePoint Online.  I have successfully used the code in this question ([Create a new link to a document using SharePoint 2010](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/6080/create-a-new-link-to-a-document-using-sharepoint-2010)) to add a link in SharePoint 2013, but using the same code for SPO results in an aspx file that doesn't reroute to the URL - clicking on it simply downloads the aspx file!

Comment: This is exactly what I am experiencing now... I have checked all the properties of my 'document' and list item and can not find any difference

Answer (score 1):

I'd comment this but I don't currently have the rep yet to do so...

Have you considered using DocIDs for SharePoint? This link shows how to activate the feature [Activate/Configure Document IDs in SharePoint](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/activate-and-configure-document-ids-in-a-site-collection-66345c77-f079-4104-ac7a-e25826849306). It'll create a new column with a unique ID on your site collection where you can link directly to it from a link similar to `<YourSiteCollection>/_layouts/15/DocIdRedir.aspx?ID=<UniqueIDFieldValue>`. It should link to the document, rather than download it... As far as I've seen it does with SharePoint 2013.